# Why does cURL return correct value but not node-libcurl?

Tags: node.js, curl, get

I am using cURL to fetch a website (which returns the error I want).

```js
$ curl 'https://matchmaker.krunker.io/seek-game?hostname=krunker.io&region=us-ca-sv&game=SV%3A4jve9&autoChangeGame=false&validationToken=QR6beUGVKUKkzwIsKhbKXyaJaZtKmPN8Rwgykea5l5FkES04b6h1RHuBkaUMFnu%2B&dataQuery=%7B%7D
```

However, when I use the `node-libcurl` package in Node.JS, I get an error 1020. Why does this happen?

```js
const { curly } = require('node-libcurl')
const url = 'https://matchmaker.krunker.io/seek-game?hostname=krunker.io&region=us-ca-sv&game=SV%3A4jve9&autoChangeGame=false&validationToken=QR6beUGVKUKkzwIsKhbKXyaJaZtKmPN8Rwgykea5l5FkES04b6h1RHuBkaUMFnu%2B&dataQuery=%7B%7D'

curly.get(url)
    .then(({ statusCode, data }) => console.log(statusCode, data))
```

Answer (score 0):

1020 is not a curl error code, and a quick google search suggest 1020 is a common-ish firewall error for Cloudflare, ref
https://community.cloudflare.com/t/error-1020-cannot-log-in-to-the-site-how-to-fix/71784

the most obvious difference for a server between a LIBcurl request and a curl request is that libcurl doesn't have an user-agent, but curl does, and it's not too uncommon to block requests lacking an user-agent (wikipedia.org is 1 example blocking requests lacking useragent),add an user-agent and try again.

```js
curly.get(url,{userAgent:"imaginate's awesome curl script"})
    .then(({ statusCode, data }) => console.log(statusCode, data))
```

Comment: I still get the error. Notice that if you load the URL using your browser, it loads. Maybe setting other parameters help? Also, [this error](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029779472-Troubleshooting-Cloudflare-1XXX-errors#error1020) means I am being denied. If you figure out any other parameters that may help, please let me know.

Comment: @imaginate hmm could be an ip block, if your node-js application and your curl requests have 2 different ip's, but add `--trace-ascii -` to your curl command, what do you get?

Comment: It’s definetly not an ip block, because i used a proxy with the same result, error 1020.